# Android webview twitter link not opening

Tags: android, webview

The link below is not opening in android `webview` .I am new to android. Someone help me to open this link in webview.

https://mobile.twitter.com/SCHOOLinSITES

I tried to open it in the following manner

**XML**

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView51" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
</WebView>
```

**Activity**

```
WebView w=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView51);    
w.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
w.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/SCHOOLinSITES");
```

Comment: Post some code or what you have tried?

Comment: Did you write any code yet? If yes, please let us know where do you find it hard.

Comment: Post your webview class and layout code

Comment: post your xml and Java code, and what happens when you try to run the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a userAgent in your Webview.

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");
webView.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/SCHOOLinSITES");
```

Comment: wait checking that site on my emulator